# Как сохранить HTML текст в БД MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Как положить кусок HTML кода в переменную, чтобы потом сохранить в БД?

HTML код:

```
$sql = 
"<td><div><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i><span class=\"class\"> Содержимое ячейки</span></div> <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-down\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i><span class=\"peer\"> Содержимое ячейки</span></td>
<td><a href=\"class\" class=\"ht" >Содержимое ячейки</a></td>
";
```

Я так делаю:
$sql кодирую в base64

```
$article_code = base64_encode($sql);
```

Затем запросом "INSERT INTO .... " сохраняю в БД.

Но видать строка огромная получается и часть теряется. Потом при выводе из БД, выводится только часть текста. 
А если вывести на странице парсера через Var_Dump, то все на месте.

**Собственно вопрос:**
Как сохраннить огромный кусок HTML кода в БД?

Comment: 1. сделать поле достаточного размера, подходящего типа (какого именно типа зависит от используемой БД) 2. не кодировать html в base64, а класть как есть (для этого не писать переменную в текст запроса, а пользоваться привязкой переменных (bind))

Comment: @Mike PDP рулит

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте тип ячейки в БД "longblob". Он позволяет поместить около 2000 000 символов. Этого хватит.

Comment: `LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT - столбец типа BLOB или TEXT, максимальная длина 4294967295 символов`